# MVC - How work Javascript in View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm sorry for my question, but I'm new in MVC.

This is my situation.

In my view, I have a Model ***(@model DAEF.Models.M_Generic***)

and I want to compare 2 fields. My question is,  how can I use the javascript

for do that ?

Below my **example** code with 2 dates.

```
    @model DAEF.Models.M_Generic

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CompareDate() {
            var dSart = "<%=model.Dat_Start%>";
            var dEnd = "<%=model.Dat_End%>";

            if (dEnd > dSart) {
                alert("Date One is greather then Date Two.");
            }
        }
        CompareDate()
    </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Ask_History", "Corr_Exit"))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dat_Start, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dat_Start, new { @class = "DateTimePicker form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dat_Start, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dat_End, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dat_End, new { @class = "DateTimePicker form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dat_End, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ToShortDateString()` and convert that string to javascript `Date` like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function CompareDate() {
                    var dSart =new Date("@model.Dat_Start.ToShortDateString()");
                    var dEnd = new Date("@model.Dat_End.ToShortDateString()");

                    if (dEnd > dSart) {
                        alert("Date One is greather then Date Two.");
                    }
                }
                CompareDate()
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing properties of the model, you do not need javascript variables.

```
function CompareDate() {
  @if (model.Dat_End > model.Dat_Start) {
    alert("Date One is greather then Date Two.");
  }
}
CompareDate();
```